# Resume last activity when launcher icon is clicked

Tags: android

As I see most of application resumes last activity when launcher icon is clicked. However it seems that this is not default behavior. In my application launcher activity is always started when launcher icon is clicked.

How can i configure my application to resume last activity when launcher icon is clicked and application is already running.

Answer (score 29):

#### Problem:

I'm not qualified to say this a bug, but this behaviour has been around since the first Android version. There is a problem with tasks and roottasks in release builds when starting the application from the launcher. You can find the related bug report [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26658).

#### Solution:

It can be fixed adding following code to your onCreate of your launcher activity:

```
if (!isTaskRoot()) {
    finish();
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This is what I needed as I have to have my launcher activity set as "singleTop" launchMode.

Comment: This did not work for me on OnePlus one. if Activity A starts Activity B and then A finishes itself. Then `isTaskRoot` returns true in Activity B but not on OnePlus one. So app used to close itself on launch only.

I used a `private static boolean isRunning` instead and checked if its true in onCreate. if not then set it true else finish. set it false in finish()

Comment: This "fix" does indeed resume the app when launcher icon is clicked, but it's definitely not a solution to be used for any app that supports deep links. Deep links are usually handled through the same launcher activity, and they should navigate somewhere in the app. With the proposed solution, the deep links won't be given a chance to be handled.

Comment: I think it makes sense to also check that `intent.data == null` in addition to the above. Haven't tested this, but intent.data will always have deep link data if the app is started from the link versus it was started from the launcher icon.

Answer (score 4):

I met the same problem, and solve it by adding 
`android:launchMode="singleInstance"` 
to the application tag inside manifest.
You can check the detail about the launchmode in

[android:launchMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode)

Comment: My issue was related to the launchMode, but user1281750 answer actually was the solution.

Comment: there is no launchMode in the application tag

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you don't exit your app? See also [Activity Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/activity_task_design.html).

Comment: Yes Im sure. In my samsung galaxy ace i have recent apps menu. When run application from recent it resumes, when from launcher it restarts.

Comment: How do you start your sub activities? With `startActivity` or with `startActivityForResult`?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the lifecycle of your Activity. See ["Activity Lifecycle"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) in the Android Developer site. If your activity is just paused it will resume if the activity comes back to the foreground thus also if you click the icon.

If you want to let the user continue the last activity even if the activity is destroyed then you must code an own solution to get to the right activity.

Answer (score 0):

This is be an ugly hack, but you could try the following:

Put a static variable called lastStopped in your application subclass (or any singleton for that matter). Set it to null by default.

In the onCreate of your first activity you'll have something like this:

```
if (MyApp.lastStopped != null) {            

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyApp.lastStopped.getClass());
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
    return;

}
```

Now any activity that you want to return to after pressing home should have:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {

    super.onStop();
    MyApp.lastStopped = this;

}
```

Make sure you clear MyApp.lastStopped when you launch another activity to prevent memory leaks.

Let me know if this works for you, it did for me!

Answer (score 0):

You can test the flag: `FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT` to catch the case when the activity was brought to front and not created.

```
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    if ((getIntent().getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT) != 0) {  
        finish(); 
        return; 
    } 

    // Regular activity creation code... 
}
```

Comment: For some reason, @Tobrun's solution doesn't work on Android 4.4. I prefer to use this solution.