# Google Play and Launcher launched separated activities

Tags: android

Let's say I have a simple app, with a `SplashScreenActivity` and a `MainActivity`.
Below is part of my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".front.activities.splashscreen.SplashScreenActivity"
        android:launchMode="standard"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".front.activities.main.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/Main_Title"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

And my `SplashScreenActivity` opens `MainActivity` in `onCreate()`.

### The Problem

If the app is launched from Google Play instead of launcher, if I pressed home and click the app icon in the launcher, one more `SplashScreenActivity` is launched again and therefore one more `MainActivity` on the backstack.

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Kill the app if it is opened.
2. Open the app from Google Play.
3. Press Home button
4. Open the app from launcher. You will know notice that `SplashScreenActivity` has been launched again (Or by looking at logs)
5. Repeat step 3-4. Each time you repeat, one more `SplashScreenActivity` and `MainActivity` is launched.

After several trials, if we press back button, we will notice that there are multiple `MainActivity` in the back stack.

#### More information

1. If the app is not started from Google Play, but from launcher at the very first time (step 2), this cannot be reproduced.
2. Not only Google play, but any other app that sends an intent to start the app can reproduce this.
3. If I first launch from launcher, and then from Google Play, 2 `SplashScreenActivity` will be launched. But if I press app icon from launcher again, it will not create a 3rd `SplashScreenActivity`. It will bring the first launched `MainActivity` to the top.

### What have I tried

1. Make `SplashScreenActivity` to `android:launchMode="singleTask"`. Does not help.
2. Make `MainActivity` to `android:launchMode="singleTask"`. This will prevent multiple `MainActivity` from being created, but does not solve the problem of starting `SplashScreenActivity` multiple times. You may also assume `MainActivity` should not be set to `singleTask`.

### What I expected

By clicking on the app icon in the launcher, Android should be able to find out that in my task manager, the app is already launched and will simply bring it to the top.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Well explained question.

Comment: Any luck with `singleInstance` launch mode for the splash activity and `singleTop` for the MainActivity?

Comment: can you try adding `android:taskAffinity=""` to both your activities.

Comment: Can you provide more of the manifest? specifically the application tag?

Answer (score 1):

Some launchers have this bug: when app is started from home screen, new instance of initial activity is created instead of resuming the app. It can be fixed by adding

```
if (!isTaskRoot()) {
    finish();
    return;
}
```

to `onCreate()` of the initial activity. 
See also:

[Resume last activity when launcher icon is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944338/resume-last-activity-when-launcher-icon-is-clicked),

[Resume the Top Activity instead of starting the Launcher Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721619/resume-the-top-activity-instead-of-starting-the-launcher-activity)

Comment: This is certainly a good alternative to prevent multiple activities in the backstack. But I do hope there will be a true solution and does not even trigger the launch of SplashScreenActivity.

Answer (score 0):

add 
`android:noHistory="true"`

tag to splash screen activity. It always populates one instance and it is not stored in the back stack as well.