# Is there a way to resume same Activity on launching application from notification and then reopening app from launcher icon?

Tags: android, xamarin

I have this scenario:

1. User clicks the notification, then app is opened and user is redirected to a particular activity (let's call it `ActivityB`).
2. Now user clicks home button, app gets minimized(`OnSaveInstanceState()` gets called).
3. i) Now if User opens the Recents, he lands back on `ActivityB`(`ActivityB` is resumed).

   ii) But, if he opens the app by clicking the app icon from home screen, then new instance is created and user lands at splash screen(`OnCreate()` gets called with `savedInstanceState` as `Null`). But I want the user to redirect the user back to `ActivityB`, same as above case. Is there a way to achieve this??

I know there are lot of similar questions, but I haven't found anything specific to my use-case.

Relevant Code:

```
var intent = new Intent(ApplicationContext, Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(SplashActivity)));
intent.SetAction(notificationBody.ClickAction);
intent.PutExtras(bundle);

var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(ApplicationContext,
    (int)DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds(), intent, PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);

var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ApplicationContext, CHANNEL_ID)
    .SetAutoCancel(true)
    .SetContentTitle(notificationBody.Title)
    .SetContentText(notificationBody.Body)
    .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

notificationManager.Notify(notificationBody.Tag ?? Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), 
    (int) DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds(), notificationBuilder.Build());
```

Comment: Have you considered the fact that os can still kill your application? Not to mention I would suggest you add the relevant code as well

Comment: Added the Relevant code

Comment: You can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944338/resume-last-activity-when-launcher-icon-is-clicked).

Comment: What's your `launchMode`? And please provide some code about Android Manifest.

Answer (score 1):

If the `android:launchMode="singleTask"` is set in your Android manifest. Try to remove it and see if this corrects the problem you described.

You can read this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html). In singleTask mode when you click the home button all the activites above the single task activity are removed from the stack.